# Splunk viewing '_value' not using mcatalog

Tags: splunk

According to Splunk, `| mcatalog values(_value) WHERE index=index-name` is not allowed. Is there another way to view `_value`'s for all the requests sent without using mcatalog?

P.S. i've looked into mstats but it only offers max, min, sum, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If the metric you're looking for has a minute frequency you can use *latest(_value)* with *mstats* and a span of 1 minute. You will get the raw value recorded by that minute measurement.

```
| mstats latest(_value) 
WHERE index=em_metrics metric_name="*" span=1m 
BY metric_name
```

Notice how the raw value changes every minute:

[image: mstats latest(_value)]

*If this fixes your problem, take a moment to accept the answer. This can be done by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in!*

Comment: Thank you! I actually came to this solution before seeing your answer, but i'm glad that you validated my solution.